# How to get rows from DF that contain value None in pyspark (spark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In below example `df.a == 1` predicate returns correct result but `df.a == None` returns 0 when it should return 1.

```
l = [[1], [1], [2], [2], [None]]
df = sc.parallelize(l).toDF(['a'])
df    # DataFrame[a: bigint]
df.collect()    # [Row(a=1), Row(a=1), Row(a=2), Row(a=2), Row(a=None)]
df.where(df.a == 1).count()   # 2L
df.where(df.a == None).count()   # 0L
```

Using Spark 1.3.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`Column.isNull`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isNull) method:

```
df.where(df.a.isNull()).count()
```

On a side note this behavior is what one could expect from a [normal SQL query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6c1d3/1). Since `NULL` marks *"missing information and inapplicable information"* [1] it doesn't make sense to ask if something is equal to `NULL`. It simply either `IS` or `IS NOT` missing.\

Scala API provides special null-safe equality `<=>` operator so it is possible to do something like this:

```
df.where($"a" <=> lit(null))
```

but it doesn't look like a good idea if you ask me.

1.[Wikipedia, Null (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)

Comment: Great answer guys. I do understand the question here is specific to pyspark but thought it might not hurt to also include how a similar logic may be resolved in Scala as well df.filter(df.col("a").isNull() or df.col("a").isNaN() ).count() I hope that was helpful

Comment: Is there a way to filter the row if ANY column is null?